# Load a PDF from internet in xcode

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I have a view controller that has a UIWebView object within it.

I would like to load and display a PDF from the internet within the UIWebView.

I have the code working to display the a PDF loaded from the resource bundle, but i am lost on having the PDF loaded from the internet.
I was thinking it would be as simple as changing the fileURLWithPath to point to the location on the internet...  although the form displays, it does not show the contents.  So I am assuming that I have the wrong URL in the string???

Does anyone have a code snippet to load and display a PDF from the internet within a UIWebView that they would be willing to share???

thanks
tony

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are looking at iOS stuff, not Mac. On iOS, it should really be just as simple as 
`NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[aWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i implemented it....

```
visitNoteViewController *controller = [[visitNoteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"visitNoteView" bundle:nil];
NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
controller.pdfUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/FeedEnclosure/utah.edu.1668842900.01668842919.1681195338/enclosure.pdf"];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for xCode 5.

Interface section - myWebView is the outlet to the UIWebView in my storyboard.

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
    @property NSURL *url;
```

The rest goes into viewDidLoad section of the ViewController class.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

_url = [[NSURL alloc] init];

_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/FeedEnclosure/utah.edu.1668842900.01668842919.1681195338/enclosure.pdf"];
[_myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: _url]];
}
```

This worked for me but there maybe a more efficient way of doing this.